# Use relative paths in Kubernetes config

Tags: kubernetes

The goal is to orchestrate both production and local development environments using Kubernetes. The problem is that `hostPath` doesn't work with relative path values. This results in slightly differing configuration files on each developer's machine to accommodate for the different project locations (i.e. `"/my/absolute/path/to/the/project"`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-service
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: app
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: some-deploy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: nginx:1.13.12-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: vol_example
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
        - name: vol_example
          hostPath:
            path: "/my/absolute/path/to/the/project"
            type: Directory
```

How can relative paths be used in Kubernetes config files? Variable replacements (such as `$(PWD)/project`) have been tried, but didn't seem to work. If config variables can work with volumes, this might help but unsure of how to achieve this.

Comment: you may go through [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/20328/files)

Comment: Also hostPath WON'T work on multi node clusters. You should definitely chek out on  the network storage options.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya, could you contextualise usage as an answer please?

Comment: Thanks @Flowkap, but that still won't resolve different paths on different development machines.

Comment: So to be frank: what's the use of this? After all: The configuration IS slightly different on dev and production. The volume paths are different.Even if you would use relativ path they would be different. So you are not overcoming configuration differences.The link aditya provided provides various ways of how to define common parts of a configuration and adding environment specifics.

Comment: After all there is no "relativ volume mount"

Comment: @Peter having a configuration file for development and production is one thing, but having different configuration files for each developer working on the project is another. For starters, each dev is likely to have a different username, i.e. "/home/myname/project/app", so storing this file in version control becomes problematic. If it were relative to the project directory, i.e. "./app", it relieves this. Does this help articulate the issue?

Comment: Yes, got the point. Still I think this topic should be addressed differently. I tend to have the perspective of setting my local environment as stage0. And I am trying to be consistent with other stages as much as possible to reduce effects corresponding to 'works on my machine'. This setup could be enforced either using images for developers workstations or by providing a provisioning tool such as ansible to ensure the setups are consistent, depending on how you manage your environments.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787) `kubectl` will never support variable substitution.

You can create a [helm](https://helm.sh/) chart for your app (yaml). It supports yaml template variables (among various other features). So you'll be able to pass  `hostPath` parameter based on development or production.

Comment: This answer should really provide an Helm chart that solves OPs problems with the given configuration...

Answer (score 2):

Not a native Kubernetes solution but you can manually edit the `.yaml` file 'on-the-fly' before applying it with `kubectl`.
In your `.yaml` file use a substitution that is not likely to become ambiguous in the `volume` section:

```yaml
volumes:
  - name: vol_example
    hostPath:
      path: {{path}}/relative/path
      type: Directory
```

Then to apply the manifest run:

```bash
 cat deployment.yaml | sed s+{{path}}+$(pwd)+g | kubectl apply -f -
```

**Note:** `sed` is used with the separator `+` because `$(pwd)` will result in a path that includes one or more `/` which is the conventional `sed` separator.

Comment: Your command where it says {{path}} should be {{pwd}}

Comment: Why? `{{path}}` needs to be changed into the value returned by `$(pwd)`

Comment: I used your solution, but your command didn't work for me. You want to replace {pwd} with $pwd, not "path:" part in the .yaml

Comment: `{{path}}` is replaced with the current working directory while running the command. The content of the yaml file should literally contain the string `{{path}}`, which is replaced by the `sed` command on the fly to be the output of `$(pwd)`.